# C++ Qt add multiple widget like QPushButton with variable Names

Tags: c++, button, qwidget, qt6

I want to add some Widget (QPushButton for example) in my central Widget inside a layout

I can do it with :

```
QPushButton *but1 = new QPushButton(ui->centralwidget);
    but1->setText("button1");
    ui->audiolayout->addWidget(but1);
```

Now my problem is that I don't know how many buttons I will have to create because it depends of the results of another function.

So what I want to do is each new button is named like

name = but + functionresult

```
int but_index;
for (but_index = 1; but_index < functionresult; but_index++)
{
QPushButton *butfunctionresult = new QPushButton(ui->centralwidget);
}
```

I can't find the correct way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widget's name isn't in `QWidget`, but in `QObject`.

Use `setObjectName(QString("but%1").arg(functionresult))`, or something similar, to set a proper name for your button, `setText(...)` for the string displayed on the button itself, and store them in a vector (if you don't need to access individually to each button by name), or a map (if you need to access them by name).

Example:

```
// Use only ONE of these containers, no need to have the two.
QVector<QPushButton*> anonymousStorage ;    // Access buttons through their index.
QMap<QString,QPushButton*> namedStorage ;   // Access buttons through an internal name.

for (auto but_index = 1 ; but_index < functionresult ; but_index++) {
    // Build the two required strings: internal name + display name.
    // "extfunc1" and "extfunc2" should return something suitable: string, integer, ... according to the current index.
    QString name = QString("button%1").arg(extfunc1(but_index)) ;
    QString display = QString("Button %1").arg(extfunc2(but_index)) ;

    // Create the button.
    auto newbut = new QPushButton(ui->centralwidget) ;
    newbut->setObjectName(name) ;
    newbut->setText(display) ;
    // Insert here any call to "connect" or other customization functions.

    // Store the new button inside ONE of these containers.
    anonymousStorage->push_back(newbut) ;
    namedStorage[name] = newbut ;
}
```

To retrieve / use them:

```
// Click on button 12 - assuming you checked it exists before, obviously...
anonymousStorage[12]->click() ;

// Click on button "Commit" - assuming you checked it exists before, obviously...
namedStorage["buttonCommit"]->click() ;
```

Comment: Thanks, thanks, THANKS, ...
I've made my tests and I can create the buttons I want.
I can execute the actions I want with
connect (anonymousStorage[1],SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(byindex()));
//    namedStorage["hls-2218"]->click();
    connect (namedStorage["hls-2218"],SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(byname()));
I think I have all I need to finish my own GUI to use yt-dlp for a specific site.
You have exactly understood what I needed.
THANKS AGAIN. @Wisblade

Comment: @NastyPhoenix Glad to help. You can accept the solution so that other users see that as solved. On the other hand, I STRONGLY encourage you to use the other `connect` syntax: `connect(anonymousStorage[1],&QPushButton::clicked,this,&<yourclassname>::byIndex)` instead since it can be syntaxically checked at compilation time - while the SIGNAL/SLOT method is checked only at runtime.

Comment: For sure will accept your answer.
I begin with C++ (but not in programming) and your advice is precious so from now I will use the syntax above.